# Get random array from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, php-5.3

I have an array like this :

```
Array
(
 [Test1] => Array
    (
       [id] => 5
     )
 [Test2] => Array
    (
       [id] => 5
    )
 )
```

I make the : `aRandomGames = array_rand ($aGameList, 1 );` but I get only the key like `Test1`, it's possible to get :

`[Test1] => Array
    (
      [id] => 5
    )`
Can you help me please ? Thx in advance and sorry for my english

Comment: You *did* read [the fine manual for `array_rand`](http://php.net/array_rand), did you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$randomKey = array_rand ($aGameList, 1 );
$aRandomGames = $aGameList[$randomKey];
```